# strace -c does not show correct seconds

Tags: linux, strace

I have got results for `strace -c` on RHEL 7 and RHEL 6 
for this command:

```
strace -c /bin/sleep 20
```

and I don't understand why the `seconds` column for `nanosleep` is equal to 0. I had expected it to be 20.

```
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           nanosleep
```

Here is a full strace report:

```
$ strace -c /bin/sleep 20 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000019           1        15        12 open
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         8         6 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0         9           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           nanosleep
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000019                    52        19 total
```

And there is a call to nanosleep in a detailed report:

```
nanosleep({20, 0}, NULL)                = 0
```

So seconds must be 20, not 0. What do you think?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410877/why-do-time-and-strace-c-differ

Comment: https://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/samplechapter/0/1/3/1/0131486829.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual page of strace(1):

> `-c`      On Linux, this attempts to show system time (CPU  time  spent running in the kernel)

I think that:

when a process calls nanosleep(), it asks the kernel to be suspended for a period of time. The kernel sets up a few things (like some flag, a timer, a timestamp...), suspends the calling process, and goes to do something else.
strace(1) reports the time spent *by the kernel* to do this, not the time the process stays suspended.

May be that this `-c` strace option can be thought as "-cost": *how much time this syscall costs?*

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually the whole quote is: `On Linux, this attempts to show system time (CPU time spent running in the kernel) **independent of wall clock time**`. So it is indeed not a clock time.

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov Yes, I've seen that "independent of ...", but seemed to me superfluous or even misleading. How can a _spent time_, aka _duration_, be dependent on wall clock? However, the guy who wrote the man page felt the need to specify.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand this question I run `strace` for `strace -c /bin/sleep`:

This is how it looked:

```
$ strace -T -o syscalls.txt -v strace -c /bin/sleep 20
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 31.54    0.000429          29        15        12 open
 13.68    0.000186          23         8           mmap
 13.60    0.000185          46         4           mprotect
 11.62    0.000158          20         8         6 stat
  6.91    0.000094          19         5           close
  5.96    0.000081          81         1           munmap
  4.63    0.000063          16         4           brk
  3.38    0.000046          46         1           arch_prctl
  3.16    0.000043          43         1           nanosleep
  2.21    0.000030          30         1           read
  1.47    0.000020          20         1         1 access
  1.32    0.000018           6         3           fstat
  0.51    0.000007           7         1           execve
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.001360                    53        19 total
```

Below is some lines from `sycalls.txt` related to the `nanosleep` syscall:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, 6498, 0, SIG_0)  = 0 <0.000028>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000017>
wait4(-1, [{WIFSTOPPED(s) && WSTOPSIG(s) == 133}], __WALL, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 3706}, ru_maxrss=616, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=205, ru_majflt=0, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=0, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=108, ru_nivcsw=1}) = 6498 <20.000423>
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=6498, si_status=SIGTRAP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

So, `nanosleep` itself lasts for 20 seconds as it is shown in the end of the line: <20.000423>. However `wait4` returns for it:

```
{ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 3706}
```

So it takes 3 microseconds to do `nanosleep` according to the report. So the `seconds` column is likely to mean `(user_time + sys_time + some-unclear-overhead)` spent by OS to handle a syscall. It is not meant to be wall time for a syscall.